# Склеить два lambda выражения в одну

Tags: c#, lambda, дерево, expressions

**Цель: собрать две лямбды в одну целую.**

```
var columnExpr = GenerateMemberExpression<Trio<int?, int?, int?>, int?>("First");

Expression<Func<GameModelRowViewModel, Trio<int?, int?, int?>>> func =
    vm => vm.ProbModelViewModels.First(x => x.Model.Name == probName).Model.ThridEvents[cfName];
```

Заранее какое свойство будет взято из класса ThridEvents неизвестно.

Метод **GenerateMemberExpression** взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5321838/7663131).

---

Послесловие (читать необязательно):

Проблема в поверхностном понимании работы "дерева выражений". В источниках, которые изучил, используются простые примеры сборки дерева выражений. Быть может кто может взять на себя такую ответственность и сделать суперпупер мануал по ним?

Comment: А что вы конкретно хотите получить? Опишите словами.

Comment: @VladD хочу получить делегат, который будет возвращать нужное поле     из словаря ThridEvents<CoefName,Trio<int,int,int>>

Сейчас по примеру получается что из func хочу получить свойство FIrst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, можно модифицировать `GenerateMemberExpression`, чтобы передавать в него ваше выражение. Получится как-то так:

```
// TSource -- тип выражения-параметра
// TModel -- тип выражения, из которого нужно взять нужное свойство по имени
// pp -- параметр
public static Expression<Func<TSource, T>> GenerateMemberExpression<TSource, TModel, T>(
    string propertyName,
    Expression source,
    ParameterExpression p)
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(propertyName);

    Expression columnExpr = Expression.Property(source, propertyInfo);

    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType != typeof(T))
        columnExpr = Expression.Convert(columnExpr, typeof(T));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, T>>(columnExpr, p);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Expression<Func<GameModelRowViewModel, Trio<int?, int?, int?>>> func =
        vm => new Trio<int?, int?, int?>() { First = 5 };
    var memberExpr =
        GenerateMemberExpression<GameModelRowViewModel,
                                 Trio<int?, int?, int?>,
                                 int?>
           ("First", func.Body, func.Parameters[0]);

    // проверка
    var m = memberExpr.Compile();
    var result = m(new GameModelRowViewModel()); // 5
}
```

---

Другой подход — через `Expression.Invoke`. Функцию `GenerateMemberExpression` можно оставить, как в вашем вопросе.

```
Expression<Func<GameModelRowViewModel, Trio<int?, int?, int?>>> func =
    vm => new Trio<int?, int?, int?>() { First = 5 };
var memberExpr = GenerateMemberExpression<Trio<int?, int?, int?>, int?>("First", func.Body);

var combined = Expression.Lambda<Func<GameModelRowViewModel, int?>>(
    Expression.Invoke(memberExpr, func.Body),
    func.Parameters);

// проверка
var m = combined.Compile();
var result = m(new GameModelRowViewModel()); // 5
```

Comment: Когда пробовал сам то думал, что метод Invoke вернет результат выполнения лямбды. Спасибо.

Comment: @adrug: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!